# How to show thumbnail View in UWP Syncfusion pdfViewer?

Tags: c#, uwp, syncfusion

I made a pdf viewing Page, I want to show thumbnail View on left side like PowerPoint. 
How to show thumbnailView on syncfusion PDF Viewer??

Answer (score 0):

From the [Syncfusion documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/uwp/pdf-viewer/how-to/disable-thumbnail-view):
The SfPdfViewer control allows you to enable and disable thumbnail view that is opened when the document is magnified below 100%. The following code illustrates the same.

```
pdfViewer.IsThumbnailViewEnabled = false; // respectively true;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but, this is active only magnified below 100%. I want to show always thumbnail Image on the left side like PPT edit page

Comment: Right. I think you need to do your own tumbnails. Convert each page to an image.

Comment: yeah, so I made another pdf viewer and align it vertically on the left side. And then mapped each page index using GoToPage() method in Click event. Thanks for ur answering!